# How to get selected date in ANTD Calendar component?

Tags: reactjs, antd

How can I get a date selected on user click in calendar component?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question is very short and it is unclear what you are asking. Please edit the question and provide more detail, such as showing us code you have tried and any error messages you have received. That way, you'll have a better chance of receiving an Answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not supported yet, trace https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/3042

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for onSelect. See the docs [here](https://ant.design/components/calendar/) To see the date selected do the following.

```
 <Calendar value={value} onSelect={(e)=>{console.log(e)}}/>
```

The e is a value passed to function on selection of any date. following is the sample output of the log

```
_d: [date] Thu Jan 05 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
_f: "YYYY-MM-DD"
_i: "2017-01-25"
_isAMomentObject: true
_isUTC: false
_isValid: true

_locale: Object

_pf: Object

__proto__: Object
```

Comment: The `onSelect` callback will also be called when the calendar panel is changed (e.g., switching months). AFAIK it does not allow to distinguish between events fired by the user clicking a date and the calendar panel being controlled by the calendar controls.

Comment: I sued this as an alternative https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-calendar